# UIButton RAC binding

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I started study MVVM pattern with Reactive Cocoa and now I have some unclear situation. I want to bind `enable` property of button with my model and bind `rac_command` also. Here is a my code :

```
RAC(self.loginButton, enabled) = RACObserve(self.viewModel, loginButtonEnabled);
RAC(self.loginButton, rac_command) = RACObserve(self.viewModel, loginCommand);

- (RACCommand *)rac_loginCommand {
    return [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
        return [RACSignal empty];
    }];
}
```

But it's doesn't work.

```
'Signal <RACDynamicSignal: 0x7f805bf05b30> name:  is already bound to key path "enabled" on object <Button: 0x7f805bc3eae0;
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

I fonund a answer. Correct way :

```
- (RACCommand *)rac_loginCommand {

    return [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:self.rac_loginButtonEnableSignal
                                   signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
                                       return [RACSignal empty];
                                   }];
}
```